# Getting Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0 Error in datatables server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

This is a frequently asked question, but I haven't found a solution in the existing threads. It typically points to a mismatch between headers and cells, but I believe that's not the case here. Maybe I'm just looking past it...

My JSON...

```
{"draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 5, "recordsFiltered": 5, "data": [{"fName":"Ida","lName":"Black"},{"fName":"Gwen","lName":"Sharp"},{"fName":"Sharon","lName":"Sullivan"},{"fName":"Claudette","lName":"Tidwell"},{"fName":"Ellie","lName":"Westman"}]}
```

My HTML...

```
                      <table id="datatable_tabletools" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>fName</th>
                                    <th>lName</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>fName</th>
                                    <th>lName</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                      </table>
```

My JS...

```
$('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "data": "../contacts/returnjson"
    });
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error?

Comment: is it definitely returning the JSON correctly? Check your network tools to see if the file is being downloaded successfully.

Comment: I don't see the name of the action in the network tab. Datatables does seem to be aware of the number of rows returned though. Although I specify 5 rows above, I was previously not doing that, and the rows displayed in datatables were correct, but blank and I got the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify data property names for each column using [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.

Also you should be using [`ajax.url`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to define data source URL if you are using Ajax-sourced data.

For example:

```
$('#datatable_tabletools').dataTable({
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": {
      "url": "../contacts/returnjson"
   },
   "columns": [
      { "data": "fName" },
      { "data": "lName" }
   ]
});
```

Comment: perfect. thanks. I don't understand why this isn't in the datatables example, but thanks.